# Unable to build relationships in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a database with these tables `RelationShips` and `Products`. I want to create relation between these tables.

```
  RelationshipId  RelationShipName  RelationShipStatus
--------------------------------------------------------
       1               Mother            True
       2               Father            True
       3               Sister            True

  ProductId  SubCategoryId  ....  RelationShipId
---------------------------------------------------
    ABC          100                 1,2...
    XYZ          101                 2,3...
```

If I make the relation with `RelationShipId`, unable to insert the data 1,2.... like this because of int data type in products (`RelationShipId`). If I give products (`RelationShipId`) as `varchar` is it possible to build relationships? Thanks

Comment: RelationshipID in Products table is a violation of 1st Normal Form and therefore not the best way to design a database.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably look at using a many to many relation shipt table.

So you would have your table

```
RelationShip
- RelationShiptID
- Etc.
```

and then

table

```
Products
- ProductID
- Etc
```

and then the Many to Many

```
ProductRelationships
- ProductID
- RelationshipID
```

Have a look at [Many-to-many (data model)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29)

Also, for a nice explanation see [Design pattern: many-to-many](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php)

Comment: But Its may be more complex in terms of maintenance.Because every time while inserting the product i have to insert those pivot tables also and i have few more these type of columns.. Please help me with respect to maintenance.